# Enter button doesn't submit comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

When adding a comment to an answer via the Android app, pressing the enter key on the soft keyboard hides the keyboard - it doesn't submit the comment.

This is the functionality on the desktop version, so shouldn't it be the same on Android?

Nexus 5 and using SwiftKey keyboard

Comment: Let me try,  It's stack exchange app, SwiftKey and micromax pressing enter now





It doesn't work...  Only post button seems option

Comment: Now on Android default browser. M going to press enter

Comment: Confirmed on Nexus 4 standard keyboard and Google Japanese IME, though I may conclude to all keyboards. Still, I have a mixed feeling for this feature, so no vote from me.

Comment: @RGraham you might as well add that as alternative suggestion. Maybe current implementation is not so clear, but personally, I still don't find it as an issue.

Comment: On the stock keyboard, the enter key does indeed show the intended "Finished" label (must be a SwiftKey Beta bug), so I've removed that part of the request. I still think it should submit the comment instead though, so leaving the question in-tact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 1.0.22 coming out soon, the app does the correct thing here.

1. The action button on the keyboard now says "Post", on keyboards that support that feature.
2. Tapping the button (or the Done, or whatever button your keyboard says) will post the comment.

[image]

Comment: Just want to inform that it should be 1.0.22, not 0.1.22. Otherwise, we're going back to alpha version?!

Comment: @Andrew fixed! :)

Answer (score -1):

Enter is blocked rather handles in Android app to return invisible char.  As you can see browser enter worked but not in app. This doesn't look like intended feauter, probably no one tested the same on android browser.