# Comments and Questions should use the same ENTER key actions

Tags: feature-request, comments, keyboard

When writing a question, the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key goes to the next line.

When adding a comment, the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is booby trapped to also hit the
comment submission button that is also present. Yes, one can then hit
the edit button to continue.

Sure, that is how HTML forms work. Well, please be consistent in the
forms you use.

See also:

- [Comment box submits when enter key is used for browser menus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254265/comment-box-submits-when-enter-key-is-used-for-browser-menus)
- [User setting for Enter key submit-behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63952/user-setting-for-enter-key-submit-behavior)
- [Comments are submitted when Enter key is pressed on a context menu item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70634/comments-are-submitted-when-enter-key-is-pressed-on-a-context-menu-item)
- [Enter button doesn't submit comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224637/enter-button-doesnt-submit-comment)
  etc.

Comment: You generally don't post multiline comments - and it *is* consistent with how it works on chat, which also uses the shift enter for newline.

Answer (score 4):

I like the comment-submit via <kbd>enter</kbd>-key. I use it all the time. If you want to write a literal new line in the comment markup, use <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>. That's also how a lot of other messaging apps in the world behave (including Stack Exchange's own chat system).

But there's no real point in making new lines in comments because even though the newline characters are preserved in the database, newlines in comments don't get rendered as new lines in the front end UI. See [How about newlines within comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/997587), which is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Comment: "_it isn't about wanting to put a real newline into a post_" other than submit the comment or enter a real newline, what could you possibly want or expect to happen? nothing?

Comment: Boy, never thought just proposing changes to designs here could cost one to lose points. I better keep my mouth shut.

Comment: @DanJacobson I think you're taking away a wrong lesson from this experience. Not that I can't sympathize with feeling dejected for downvotes on meta, but at least you can learn to clearly convey your own thoughts from the get-go: what exactly do you think is problematic about current behaviour? why you think a change would be beneficial? In fact- there _is_ an inconsistency in the UI- but you didn't mention it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89361/997587

Comment: Thanks, but it's like if I recommend City Hall have a new coat of paint,
if my idea is popular, I get award money (stack reputation points), if
my idea isn't popular, I lose money. Hence merely suggesting things here
on meta carries a risk. It's just plain too risky for me to even discuss
this further.

Comment: @DanJacobson on the bright side, you can never have less than 1 unit of "currency". Getting a downvote at 1 rep has no effect on current or future rep. And downvotes carry way less weight to rep than upvotes. It takes 5 downvotes to cancel a single upvote. Downvotes are really not a reason to be dissuaded from further participation. As I've already said, what _can_ do have have your ideas better received is to put more thought and care into communicating them. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333476/997587